# How to execute Blazor-compiled code in the same timezone non-Blazor-compiled code?

Tags: .net

We have some code that can be called either on a backend .NET server, or may be called via Blazor-compiled (client) WebAssembly code.

We've set up our backend server to always operate under the UTC timezone.

Without any changes, the Blazor-compiled WebAssembly will execute on the user's browser timezone, causing inconsistency in behaviour.

How can I go about ensuring that the Blazor-compiled code executes in UTC?

Answer (score 0):

Call `Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("TZ", "UTC")` somewhere in your blazor-compiled code, during some initialization step.